# Using async and collections

Tags: .net, entity-framework, async-await, c#-5.0

I wish to download a large number of files with httpclient, performs some time consuming but not expensive computation on them, and then add the result to my database after running some query that shows that it is not already there.

How can I do this conceptually (just the locations of the awaits and the like would be helpful)

I currently have the following:

get list of addresses
add (await the web page download, then continue processing) to a list of Task
foreach element of the list, await on it, and then add it to the database.

However, it seems that this is essentially running it serially.

How should this be designed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set up a pipeline using `TPL Dataflow`. You post the addresses and the actors are:

1. Web page download
2. Processing
3. Add to DB

Use `async` wherever you can (as long as the operation is truly asynchronous) and set a high `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to allow `TPL` to choose the optimal value by itself.

Comment: Do you mean use the primitives that it provides (actionblock, bufferblock, etc) or something else? If you mean the primitives, can you please explain which ones? I am not at all familiar with TPL.

Comment: Well, yes. The easiest way is to use ActionBlock for all of them. You only need to give it a method (`WebPageDownload` for example) and remember to "send" it to the next ActionBlock at the end. The more "correct" way is to also use TransformBlocks

Comment: Is there a nice way of having a trasformblock later in the chain post to a transform block that is earlier in the chain?

Comment: @soandos There's no technical problem with it. It just needs to have a reference to the earlier block. But if you do that it stops being a simple pipeline and you're in danger of a continuous loop.

Comment: But what am I looping on? is `download.InputCount != 0 && Download.OutputCount != 0 && process.OutputCount != 0 && process.InputCount != 0` (the looping ones) correct?

Comment: When you say loop do you mean a while loop? Because you don't need one. You just give the block a method to run on every item once.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the downloads/processing running in parallel and await them all to complete. The code would look something like this:

```
// get a collection of "hot" Tasks running in parallel
var tasks = myCollection.Select(x => DownloadAndProcessAsync(x));

// await the completion of all Tasks
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: There's no point of waiting for all of the tasks to complete before moving on with what's already finished

Comment: The method inside the lambda was intended to download and perform all processing for a single item. Updated the method name to reflect that.